# How to use the Android light sensor in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I want to use the light sensor on Android with Unity. Unity can't do this and there is no asset/plugin on the store who could do that. And google isn't so frendly with this question...

Comment: Because it takes me some time to handle this problem and haven't  seen any solution on the web. So I wanted to share it to prevent others to struggle like me. And I choose Stack Overflow for the visibility. When I search on google I prefer a SO link more than a blog link. (And I haven't a blog by the way)

Comment: If it was a very specific question I should elaborate it. But in fact my question was literally "I want to get the value of the light sensor in unity" and except a plugin that cost 45$ there is no answer. So I gave mine. When people have problems in their code they have to give the maximum of information, but it's not the case here.

Comment: I think this is a very helpful question and answer. I have done something similar before and know many people want to do it too and this should help them out. The only difference is that I use `UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage`  to call a C# function when the sensor value changes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Simple version

This part explain how to use my code.

1. Put the `.jar` file into `Assets/Plugins/Android` folder
2. Then simply add the script `LightSensorPluginScript.cs` on the GameObject you wanted.
3. Then if you want to get the sensor value:

   ```
   TextMesh tm;
   LightSensorPluginScript test;
   void Start() {
       tm = transform.GetComponent<TextMesh>();
       test = GetComponent<LightSensorPluginScript> ();
   }
   void Update() { 
       tm.text = test.getLux().ToString();
   }
   ```
4. All the files can be found in this [zip archive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2siD9I5cXwtSGJHUVpqMHBibVU/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-JyhFHqzP8QG1Gv-dUv1PRw)

## Detailed version

This part explain how to create the plugin.

First of all you have to create an Android library. If you are using Android Studio, they are converted into `.aar` files. Extract them like a zip file and you will find a `classes.jar` file which is the correct `.jar` you want. You can rename it as you want, Unity didn't care.

**Android Java code**

```
public class LightSensorLib{

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mSensorRot;
    private float lux = -1000;

    public void init(Context context) {
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mSensorRot = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);

        SensorEventListener mySensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                float sensorData[];

                if(event.sensor.getType()== Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT) {
                    sensorData = event.values.clone();
                    lux = sensorData[0];
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {}
        };
        mSensorManager.registerListener(mySensorEventListener, mSensorRot, 500);
    }

    public float getLux () {
        return lux;
    }
}
```

Then I have a C# script who does the bridge between Android Java and Unity

**C# Bridge code**

```
public class LightSensorPluginScript : MonoBehaviour {
    private AndroidJavaObject activityContext = null;
    private AndroidJavaObject jo = null;
    AndroidJavaClass activityClass = null;

    void Start () {
        #if UNITY_ANDROID
        activityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        activityContext = activityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

        jo = new AndroidJavaObject("com.etiennefrank.lightsensorlib.LightSensorLib");
        jo.Call("init", activityContext);
        #endif
    }

    public float getLux() {
        #if UNITY_ANDROID
        return jo.Call<float>("getLux");
        #endif
    }
}
```

Now you can do what is explained in the `Simple version` part of this post to use the sensor.

If you want any precision I would be glad to answer and update the post.

For the IOs version I'm sorry but I have no mac to develop this... So if you want to lend me one I would be glad to do it.

I could add it as a plugin on the asset store but it feels a bit cumbersome. So I prefer to post it on StackOverflow where the post editor is really neat.

At last I hope it helps some developers.

Answer (score -2):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;

public class LightSensorPluginScript : MonoBehaviour {
private AndroidJavaObject activityContext = null;
private AndroidJavaObject jo = null;
AndroidJavaClass activityClass = null;
public TextMesh tm;
LightSensorPluginScript test;


void Start () {
    #if UNITY_ANDROID
    activityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    activityContext = activityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

    tm = transform.GetComponent<TextMesh>();
    test = GetComponent<LightSensorPluginScript>();




jo = new AndroidJavaObject("com.etiennefrank.lightsensorlib.LightSensorLib");
    jo.Call("init", activityContext);
    #endif
}

public float getLux() {
    #if UNITY_ANDROID
    return jo.Call<float>("getLux");
    #endif
}

void Update()
{

    tm.text = test.getLux().ToString();
}
```

}